# How can I rescue this lemon tree?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, citrus, lemons

I've been growing a lemon tree from a store-bought lemon seed for about half a year now. A few days ago the temperatures have started to increase and since then the tree looks dried out, even though the soil is moist and has been watered regularly.

[image]

Since I was suspecting a heat stroke, I've placed the plant inside in half-shadow, but nothing seems to happen already for around a week. The leaves aren't crispy, but just curled up.
I've fertilized the soil and also placed it in an open, north-facing window to provide some air movement. Also increasing the local air humidity with a tray didn't seem to have any effect so far.

**What exactly is wrong with the lemon tree? How can I rescue it?**

On the internet I found that this might be an issue with the roots. Can I trim them somehow?

Comment: How is your lemon right now?

Comment: Is there any news?

Answer (score 1):

The little lemon tree will be quite alright after some water has been given. Two or three days will be enough.

Important things not to do: don't overwater; do not change the position drastically, a bit of shade (umbrella) is enough; don't fertilize; most importantly: don't panic!